# How can I add html to this page?

Tags: php, html, echo

I need to add html to this page without echoing it. I only want to display it if there is a session id.

```
<?php 
session_start();
//home.php
if($_SESSION['id'])
{
echo "Welcome ,".$_SESSION['username'] ;
echo "<br /><br /><a href='/login/logout.php'>Logout</a>" ;
echo "<br /><br /><a href='edit.php'>Edit Profile</a>" ;
echo "<br /><br /><a href='/profiles/".$_SESSION['username']."'>View Profile</a>" ;
}
else
{
echo "You don't belong here!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
<?php 
session_start();
//home.php
if($_SESSION['id'])
{
?>
Welcome , <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>
<br /><br /><a href='/login/logout.php'>Logout</a>
<br /><br /><a href='edit.php'>Edit Profile</a>
<br /><br /><a href='/profiles/<?php $_SESSION['username'] ?>'>View Profile</a>
<?php
}
else
{
echo "You don't belong here!";
}
?>
```

alternatively...

```
<?php 
session_start();
//home.php
if($_SESSION['id'])
{
echo <<< END
Welcome , $_SESSION[username]
<br /><br /><a href='/login/logout.php'>Logout</a>
<br /><br /><a href='edit.php'>Edit Profile</a>
<br /><br /><a href='/profiles/$_SESSION[username]'>View Profile</a>
END;
}
else
{
echo "You don't belong here!";
}
?>
```

You may have to validate syntax, etc.  I don't have an immediate way of testing these, so they were free-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're setting $_SESSION["id"] somewhere (e.g. when the user logs in) this should work

```
if (isset($_SESSION["id"]))
   {
   // output HTML here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just redirect if there is no ID?

```
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['id'])
{
   header( 'Location: /noentry.html' ) ;
}
else
{

.....
```